# React Native : Why 'npm run ios' just hangs

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-ios

After running `npm run ios` it opens the simulator and gets stuck there, My app doesn't install on the simulator at all.
My Console has this screen

[image]

`npm i -g create-react-native-app`

`create-react-native-app my-project`

`cd my-project`

`npm run ios`

in my case i had to run `sudo npm run ios` because i get this error when running `npm run ios`

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/myusername/.expo/log'`

This is how i created my app [react intro to creating apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app.html)

Comment: Sanity check: You're on macOS right? If you're using CRNA, you'll have to run `npm start` then press `i` to start the simulator when prompted.

Comment: yes i am on Mac,  I did that. I still get same issue. I will update my question to give more info.

Comment: Just run the same set of commands you mentioned on my mac and it ran fine. My `create-react-native-app` version is 0.0.6. Try upgrading if need be.

Comment: Have you tried running the app on the simulator through XCode? It may give you some actual debugging output.

Comment: fubar, Xcode would nid a .xcodeproject file if i am not mistaken. my commands didnt produce a project file.
@ManasJayanth - How do i check version and how do i upgrade it

Comment: @AfricaMatjie  To check your version: `create-react-native-app --version` To update: npm update -g create-react-native-app. (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-global-packages)

Oh and 1.0.0 is the latest version and things work fine.

Comment: i have **create-react-native-app version: 1.0.0**